# Interprocessor Communication driver , user space interraction

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am writing a platform  driver for an IPC, (inter processor communication device )
this component generates interrupts when you write to its registers.

0- How to know if the interrupts  have been generated

1-I would like to intercept these interrupts in Userspace and trigger a function , how can i do this .

2-this driver (platform type ) is a loadable module, it probes well, but does not appear in /dev, I would like to use a file descriptor  - or other way- to communicate with it (like on a char device drivers ) can i register  it as a char driver (min, maj) just to use the file in the user space and implement some file operations while keeping my  probe registration way .
is there another  way to communicate with it in user space .

Comment: **0.** `cat /proc/interrupts` will show you that. Or any debug or trace prints in the IRQ handler. **1.** You need to write rather user space driver then. Check with UIO framework. **2.** Why do you need that? You may use many other ways, but if you want to check harder way, implement the character device interface in your driver (not recommended for such type of the devices).

Comment: You could consider using the [common mailbox framework](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/mailbox.html) in the kernel for your driver. For test purposes, there is a "mailbox-test" (`CONFIG_MAILBOX_TEST`) client driver that can be accessed from userspace via debugfs, but if you want userspace access post development, you could write a char driver based on that.